# RecyclerView Expanded Item shadow / elevation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, layout-animation

**Edit**:
In my Recyclerview the `itemViews` can expand and collapse.
The `expandView` is a layout which gets `inserted` under the `clickedItemPosition`. Everything works fine, but in following to the **Google Material Design** Guide-Lines the expanded items should have an **shadow** under and above the expanded Item. As example Google's Dialer Calllog.
How can I achieve an shadow affect above and below the clicked item?

Already tried to handle the shadow in the items above and below with animating the alpha value but therefore i need to notifyItemChanged() which doesnt really look great.

Any suggestions?
Greetings